# how to compare the lsblk disk size values to disk size values from df -h

Tags: linux, bash, disk-usage, fdisk, lsblk

I want to compare the size of the disk between the size from `df` -h to `lsblk`
Because we performed `resize2fs` , and after `resize2fs` I want to check the size from `df -h` against the size from `lablk`

So we have the following from `lsblk`

```
lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                  8:16   0    4G  0 disk /data1
sdc                  8:32   0    4G  0 disk /data2
sdd                  8:48   0    4G  0 disk /data3
```

from df -h

```
df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb                    3.9G   22M  3.8G   1% /data1
/dev/sdc                    3.9G   18M  3.8G   1% /data2
/dev/sdd                    3.9G   18M  3.8G   1% /data3
```

So I did the following in my bash script

```
[[ ` lsblk | grep "^sdb" | awk '{print $4}'  ` == ` df -h | awk -v disk_var="sdb" '$1 ~ disk_var' | awk '{print $2}'  ` ]] && echo "val are equal " || echo "val are not equal "
```

So I get from above value are not equal , in spite the values should be the same

Any suggestion how to use “`df -h`” in order to get readable size values that we can compare as the values from `lsblk`?

**we are working on rhel 7.6 server**

Answer (score 1):

From the respective manuals:

*df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system containing each file name argument.*

*lsblk  lists  information about all available or the specified block devices.*

IOW, `df` shows how much actual data each partition may hold, while `lsblk` shows raw block devices and their sizes.

Meanwhile you can make `lsblk` show the same information as `df` using the appropriate fields:

`lsblk -b -o NAME,FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT` and `df -B1` match exactly.

I'm only confused with `df` free space available as percentage values. They look very off. For instance for my root partition, in terms of raw bytes I get `31.9%` which when rounded equals `32%` and matches `lsblk` output but `df` says `34%` which is way off.

Comment: but we get it in bytes as 428448153

Comment: df -B1 | awk -v disk_var="sdb" '$1 ~ disk_var' | awk '{print $2}'
4284481536

Comment: lsblk -b -o NAME,FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT
lsblk: unknown column: FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT

Comment: Please update your `util-linux` package.

Comment: rpm -qa | grep util-linux
util-linux-2.23.2-59.el7.x86_64

Comment: Grab a version from RHEL8 ( https://www.tecmint.com/centos-alternative-distributions/ ) - not sure it will work though, or compile it from src.rpm. I'm rocking util-linux-2.36.1-1.fc33.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You can create variables to start

```
df=$(df -h | awk '/sdb/{printf "%.0f\n", $2}' | tr -d 'M|G|T')
blk=$(lsblk | awk '/sdb/ {printf "%.0f\n", $4}' | tr -d 'M|G|T')
```

Then run your test with them.

```
[[ $blk -eq $df ]] && echo "val are equal " || echo "val are not equal "
```

Comment: we get null  from  blk=$(lsblk | awk '/sd-/ {printf "%.0f\n", $4}' | tr -d 'M|G|T')

Comment: we get null from  df -h | awk '/sd/{printf "%.0f\n", $2}' | tr -d 'M|G|T')

Comment: @yael Strange. It works in my lab.  Be sure to put in the drive you are testing for e.g `sdb`